How to Configure Google Auth Redirect URI for a Node.js Application on AWS EC2?
I'm currently deploying a Node.js application that uses Google OAuth 2.0 for authentication on an AWS EC2 instance. However, when users attempt to log in using Google, they receive an "access blocked" message indicating that the redirect URI is not authorized.
My EC2 instance is running fine.
Do anyone know what to add in the callback URL of google auth?
I have added the IPV4 public key and still it not working
